# make a simple jquery mobile app with a json api

Tags: jquery-mobile, jsonp

I have a remote server that serves json, what is the easiest way to implement a jquery mobile app that will display those json data? I want a big picture description of what I should do so I can find out the detail on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve the mobile website on your own site, [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) would be enough. If you want to use [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to make it a mobile app, you should use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp) to get your data.

You could use a [template system](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) were you could drop your JSON data.
In combination with `$.mobile.changePage($.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", { "Name" : "John Doe" }));` a new page can be shown.